# Selenium with java - Need to click on a button which is in a <div> <ul> <li>?

Tags: java, selenium

I need to get click in a button which is located in `<div><ul><li>` tags.
I need to click on the third list with the class `class="icon-link exp-icon-magnify"`

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-blue"> 
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
      <li class="disabled"> 
        <a title="Wachten op Melding" href="#" class="icon-link exp-icon-bell" 
            data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"> 
        </a>
      </li             
      <li class="divider"></li>             
      <li> <a title="Voer zoekactie uit" 
           href="/collections/toolbar/Search.mvc" class="icon-link exp-icon- 
           magnify" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"> 
           </a> 
      </li>
```

Tried locating it with xpath and by cssSelector, they are not working.
Someone can please help me?

Comment: Which selector strings have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the CSS.

```
a.icon-link.exp-icon-.magnify
```

[image]

If you want to include the hierarchy check below.

```
div.navbar.navbar-blue  ul a.icon-link.exp-icon-.magnify
```

[image]

Comment: wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.icon-link.exp-icon-.magnify")));
            WebElement searchButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.icon-link.exp-icon-.magnify"));
            searchButton.click();

Not working :(

Comment: Are you getting NoSuchElement expectpion? Post the error  here.

Comment: Driver not loaded...
Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.cssSelector: div.navbar.navbar-blue  ul a.icon-link.exp-icon-.magnify (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: Ok, first thing first. Have you checked if the css working in the chrome browser dev tools as I shown in the screenshot?

Comment: omg sorry those dont work. 
These i find a 1/1 
a[title='Voer zoekactie uit'][class*='magnify'] and also this one [href*='Search.mvc'][class*='magnify']

Comment: but they are still giving exceptions back. But a guy asked me if there is a iframe above the tags and possibly blokcing it. I checked and find the following.
<iframe src="toolbar/Show.mvc" id="ifrUserTools" name="ifrUserTools" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="907.5px" height="60px">
                    </iframe>
Do you experience with this ?

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the chrome browser devtools section above the css search ?

Comment: I was about to ask if it have any iframes. Yes, the elements are in iframe. So you have to switch to iframe using the id.

Answer (score 0):

css selector would be :

```
a[title='Voer zoekactie uit'][href*='Search.mvc'][class*='magnify']
```

try adding explicit wait in your code for more stability.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a[title='Voer Zoekactie uit'][href*='Search.mvc'][class*='magnify']"))); 
button.click();
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194976/discussion-on-answer-by-cruisepandey-selenium-with-java-need-to-click-on-a-but).

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebdriverWait` and `elementToBeClickable` and the following xpath to click on the element.

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,40);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='navbar navbar-blue']//ul[contains(@class,'nav navbar-nav')]//li//a[@class='icon-link exp-icon-bell'][@title='Wachten op Melding']"))).click();
```

---

If you want to use cssselector try that.

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,40);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.navbar.navbar-blue ul.nav.navbar-nav li.disabled a.icon-link.exp-icon-bell[title='Wachten op Melding']"))).click();
```

### Edit

Switch to `iframe` first then use the above code to access the element.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("ifrUserTools");
```

Comment: Possibly iframe is there which might blocking to access the element.can you check if any iframe present above the element you have posted.

Comment: no ifram. There is a <body id="toolbarBody" onhelp="return false;"> and some more scripts between the div and <body> i see

Comment: i found an i frame you were right ... <iframe src="toolbar/Show.mvc" id="ifrUserTools" name="ifrUserTools" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="907.5px" height="60px">
                    </iframe>

Comment: so what now? no experience with this

Comment: @YalcinBatur : check the Edit option. switch to iframe first and then use the above code.Hope this will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect help everyone!

THis worked:

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("ifrUserTools"));
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("[href*='Search.mvc'][class*='magnify']")));
            WebElement searchButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[href*='Search.mvc'][class*='magnify']"));
            searchButton.click();

Answer (score 0):

You can find the element like this

```
By.xpath(""//ul[@class='navbar-nav'//li[3]]");
```

Please try with the above code and let me know